# IFrame with html content in IE11 gives navigation to the webpage was cancelled

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-11, src

I have an IFrame with src set to the html content that I receive from a web service. This html content has meta

`http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"`

in the head but in IE11, I am getting "Navigation to the webpage was cancelled" message within the IFrame.

I also get a pop up with "You will need a new app to open this data" in IE.

The iframe content is however displayed well and good in Chrome.

Things I tried to make it work in IE:

1) Replace iframe src with srcdoc. Did not work.

2) Enable Launching programs and files in Iframe in IE settings. Did not work.

3) Set Default app setting as IE as default browser. Did nothing.

Nothing works. Please suggest a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may receive this error message when a site or program is in a different Internet Explorer Security Zone.

You can try to disable the protected mode to check whether it solves your issue or not.

Further, You can try to set the IE security to low level and make a test again.

You can also try to reset the IE to it's default setting and check whether it helps to solve the issue.

You can refer the link below that may give you some additional information on this topic.

[Navigation is canceled when you browse to Web pages that are in different Internet Explorer security zones](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/967941/navigation-is-canceled-when-you-browse-to-web-pages-that-are-in-differ)